# Scraping addresses using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

First of all, I have to say that I am starting with Python. I would like to grab addresses from a webpage that is built with a script. I try to use Python 3.x and Selenium. The simple code generates a full list of shops, but I want to split it to build a table with named columns( Name, street, zip code etc). I hope that there is a smart solution.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="E:/Dysk Google/Dokumenty/chromedriver")
browser.get("http://hilding.pl/materace-mazowieckie.html")        
shops=browser.find_element_by_id('div_province')
print(shops)
browser.close()
```

Comment: Where is your code that gets name, street, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below script. Here is how you can go to get `name`, `street`, `zipcode` etc.

```
from selenium import webdriver 

Browser = webdriver.Chrome() ##If necessary, include the path
Browser.get("http://hilding.pl/materace-mazowieckie.html")

for items in Browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#div_province .shop"):
    name = items.find_element_by_css_selector(".name").text
    street = items.find_element_by_css_selector(".streat").text
    zip_code = items.find_element_by_css_selector(".zipcode").text
    print(name,street,zip_code)

Browser.quit()
```

Partial Output:

```
SALON NAP ul. Jagielska 73 02-886
SALON NAP/ DOMOTEKA ul. Malborska 41 03-286
SALON NAP ul. Mysia 3 00 - 496
SKLEP ECCELENT DOMOTEKA ul. Malborska 41 03-286
SKLEP ECCELENT, C.H. MEGA MEBLE al. Jerozolimskie 200 02-486
SKLEP ECCELENT, CH JUPITER ul. Towarowa 22 00-839
```

Comment: Thanks! It's what I want to get! How can I export this to excel file with named columns?